# Space in the ruby array by %w

Tags: ruby, arrays

How can I add space character in the ruby array if I want to use %w(a b c) syntax?

Comment: They `%w()` syntax is meant as a shortcut to serve a common case. I would recommend using the more verbose syntax `['a', ' ', 'b']` in this case. More readable, less surprising to other coders.

Answer (score 187, accepted):

Escape it:

```
%w(a b\ c) # => ["a", "b c"]
```

Comment: Thanks. After your answer i understand how i can do it. I wanted just this - %w(a  \  b c) # => ["a", " ", "b", "c"]

Comment: While this is a "correct" answer, it is horribly unreadable, which defeats the purpose of `%w`. Don't do this.

Comment: That is actually kind of clever @VasiliyErmolovich.  Ruby has all sorts of "tricks" and I'm always finding new ways to express things with the language.  As unreadable as it may be, its neat that the Ruby language supports the syntax in your reply in the first place!

Comment: It's fair to point out that the [Ruby community style guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#percent-w) only prefers this syntax when you're creating an array of *words*: "non-empty strings without spaces and special characters". So you're right, you should probably never do the thing I've suggested.

Answer (score 16):

Try this:

```
>> a = %w(a\  b c)
=> ["a ", "b", "c"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
>> a = %W[a \s b]
=> ["a", " ", "b"]
```