# Is it possible to create a nil value in an array using %w[] shorthand?

Tags: ruby, arrays

Say I want to create an array with `["one", "two", nil]`, is it possible to do so using shorthand `%w[]` syntax? Obviously this does not work:

```
array = %w[one two nil]
=> ["one", "two", "nil"]
array[2].nil?
=> false
```

Ruby 1.9.3

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12979928/create-array-with-empty-string-using-w (there the results contain an empty string - so it is a similar situation, not the same). Another similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4064062/space-in-the-ruby-array-by-w

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. The whole purpose of that convenience syntax is to avoid putting quotes around string literals, and the separator comma.

Comment: Your answer reflects the *spirit* of the %w[] constructor, but a more forgiving read of the question might be "Is it possible to create nil values while using the %w[] constructor?" In that case, the answer is clearly yes.

Comment: @CodeGnome Actually, the question clearly states _using_ the `%w[]` constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You could splat the `%w[]` array and put the `nil` after:

```
>> array = [ *%w[one two], nil, *%w[and some more words] ]
=> ["one", "two", nil, "and", "some", "more", "words"]
```

But that might be noisier than just quoting the strings individually; OTOH, the extra noise does indicate that something odd is going on so readers would be encouraged to look closer.

Answer (score 0):

Only indirectly. You can create your array, and then convert the string "nil" to an actual nil with Array#collect:

```
array = %w[one two nil].collect { |v| v == 'nil' ? nil : v }
```