# Create array with empty string using %w[]

Tags: ruby, syntax

To create an array with empty strings `['a', '', 'b', '', 'c']` (not one space strings `' '`), using `%W` I can use `%W[a #{} b #{} c]`, also I can concatenate arrays, but is it possible to create array with empty strings using just `%w[]`?

Comment: no. %w[] has no way to represent zero-length string as an element.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4064062/space-in-the-ruby-array-by-w (there the results contain a space - so it is a similar situation, not the same)

Comment: @knut: I know about escaping space, but that is not what I want

Answer (score 19):

A couple of options

`%W[a b c #{''} z]`

`%W[a b c] << " "`

(I know this isn't using the `%w{}` syntax, but for good measure:

`'a,b,c,,z'.split(',')`

Comment: the first option given here is the best IMO. should be marked the correct answer

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
 %w[a \   b \  c].map(&:strip)
```

,but I think it's not very clean.

Answer (score -1):

try using %W instead of %w and use \s  escape character for the empty string

```
 %W[a \s b ]
```

Comment: `%W[a \s b ]` gives `['a', ' ', 'b']` instead of `['a', '', 'b']`

Comment: u can use %W[a #{""} b ] or %W[a #{String.new} b ] or %W[a #{} b], but i couldn't find any way you can get a empty string using %w

Comment: this might help.  %w[a b].insert(1, nil.to_s)

Comment: use the first suggestion in professormeowingtons's answer above